# silverlight - Data binging issue with my class

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I am new to WPF/SL. I am facing following problem with data binding in silverlight.

Scenario-1 --> Binding Textbox's Text property with Rectangle's Fill property -- Works fine

```
<Canvas>
<Rectangle x:Name="myrect" Fill="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="50" MinHeight="40" Width="100" Canvas.Left="213" Canvas.Top="202"/>
    <Button Height="30" Width="50" Content="Add Age" Click="Button_Click" Canvas.Left="51" Canvas.Top="113"></Button>
    <TextBox x:Name="mytb" Canvas.Left="227" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" Canvas.Top="114" Height="30" Width="100"/>
</Canvas>

----------------------------------------------------------------
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myrect.DataContext = mytb;
        }

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                mytb.Text = "orange";
            }
```

But when I create a class PERSON with property name and bind this property with Fill property of rectangle, it doesn't work.

```
namespace SilverlightApplication9
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
------------------------------------------------
namespace SilverlightApplication9
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {

        Person person = new Person();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myrect.DataContext = person;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           person.Name = "orange";
        }

    }
}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <Canvas>
    <Rectangle x:Name="myrect" Fill="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="50" MinHeight="40" Width="100" Canvas.Left="213" Canvas.Top="202"/>
        <Button Height="30" Width="50" Content="Add Age" Click="Button_Click" Canvas.Left="51" Canvas.Top="113"></Button>
        <TextBox x:Name="mytb" Canvas.Left="227" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" Canvas.Top="114" Height="30" Width="100"/>
    </Canvas>
```

I don't understand where I am wrong. Appreciate any help you can provide

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part you're missing is `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  The .NET Framework does not have property notifications built in, so you need to have your source models implement this interface to notify the presentation framework of any changes.

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name 
    { 
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _name;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```